# Check if a given sequence of moves for a robot is circular or not

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence of moves for a robot, check if the sequence is circular or not. A sequence of moves is circular if first and last positions of robot are same. A move can be on of the following.

G - Go one unit
  L - Turn left
  R - Turn right

Input:path[] = "GLGLGLG"

Output: Given sequence of moves is circular

This question can be solved easily:http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-sequence-of-moves-for-a-robot-is-circular-or-not/

My Question is what if we are only given a certain path and the robot can move on to that path infinite times.
Ex:
Input:path[]="GL"

So robot can move on this path 4 times thus a cycle is possible.

Please suggest some approach to check if a cycle is possible or not with the given path.

Comment: Hint: Think about the initial and final directions in which the robot is facing after 1 iteration.

Comment: A "fail early" condition could be if the start position and end position are different but the start direction and end direction are the same there's no chance of a cycle.

Answer (score 5):

The result of performing a path from a starting point (x,y) and a starting direction d in {0,1,2,3} is two-fold:

1. Moving from (x,y) to (x',y')
2. Changing the direction from d to d'

Case 1: d == d'

There is no direction change. We either move away from the origin or not. In other words: cyclic if and only if (x,y) == (x',y')

Case 2: d == (d' + 2) mod 4

There is 180° direction change. Performing the path a second time will move the exact same vector back from (x',y') to (x,y). Cyclic.

Case 3 (Last): d == (d' + 1) mod 4 or d == (d' + 3) mod 4

There is a 90° direction change (either clockwise or counter-clockwise). Performing the path four times will move the exact same vector around a "rectangle" from (x,y) to (x + dx, y + dy), to (x + dx - dy, y + dy + dx), to (x + dx - dy - dx, y + dy + dx - dy), to (x + dx - dy - dx + dy, y + dy + dx - dy - dx) = (x, y), where dx = x'-x, dy = y'-y. Cyclic.

Thus the algorithm is fairly straight forward:

- Simulate path once starting with (x,y) == (0,0) and d = 0
- return cyclic iff d' != 0 || (x',y') == (0,0)

Comment: :I am facing difficulty in understanding your logic.

Comment: If you let the robot walk along the path for one iteration, there are four outcomes re: direction change: 0°, 90°, 180°, 270°.If there is no direction change (0°), repeating the path can only result in a loop if the robot returns to the origin after one iteration. Otherwise we are moving away from the origin. If the direction change is 180°, we are facing backwards after one iteration. Iterating it one more time is walking back to the origin since we are "mirroring" our steps. If the direction change is either 90° or 270°, we need to iterate four times to go back to the origin.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by applying algorithm given in link for given sequence repeated 4 times.

Why?

After each sequence your direction can change:

- One to the left/right (in clockwise). Then after next three times
  your direction will be same as initial.
- Two to the left/right (in clockwise). Then after next sequence your
  direction will be same as initial, also after next three.
- Zero. Of Course your direction is same as initial, also after next
  three.

If after a few sequences your direction is the same as initial it mean the moves you are going to make will be the same as previous and after 4 sequences your direction always will be the same as initial.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are not back at origin at the end of your path (that is covered by the original problem).
Now let |L| be the number of left turns and |R| be the number or right turns; and let (x,y) be your position at the end of the path.

```
switch ( (|L|-|R|) % 4 ) {
case 0: you'll be facing the same direction at the end as you did originally, so you will never get back.
case 1: you'll be facing left at the end, so repeating the path will move you by (-y, x). So you'll get back after 4 repetition of the path while the endpoints of the paths will form a square that you cover in a counter-clockwise order.
case 3: Similar to case 1, just you cover the square in clockwise order.
case 2: you'll be facing backwards, so repeating the path will move you by (-x,-y). "There and back again..."
}
```

So if all you need is a yes/no answer then just count L's and R's, and look at (|L|-|G|)%4. If that's 0 then you also need to execute the original algorithm to see if you got back to origin.